# In 2D Array, How Can I Derive the Cell Position from Text Size and Number of Columns?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I'm not exactly sure how to word this but I'll do my best. So I have a string, say "HelloWorld" and I put that into a 2d array that has 4 columns:

```
0 1 2 3
_______
H E L L
O W O R
L D
```

I want to be able to find the order number of the cell where 'W' is, based on the number of columns and the string size. 
Ex. Given the string size and the number of columns, how can I derive the position of 'W'? In other words, 'W' is in position 5 assuming the number order of the cells looks like this:

```
0 1  2  3
4 5  6  7
8 9 10 11
```

But how can I figure that out based on the number of columns and the string size? I'm trying to do it in a for loop based on the index of the column and such as well. I know the number of rows by taking the ceiling of `text size/num of cols`, in this case which is 3.

Comment: In the second snippet, with the numbers, look at each column... Don't you notice a pattern there?

Comment: Let c be the number of columns in grid and i be the index in str, then `i = c * x + y`, and `(x, y) = (i/c, i%c)`. This is the conversion for one into other.

Comment: @v78 could you elaborate a bit? So say for instance I want to see if there is anything in position 10. Given column 2 (0 based), and the number of rows (3), how can I find that with what you've said?

Comment: Your question is unclear. So are you given the 2D array, the number of columns and the string and told to find the 2D array index of `'W'`? (or something similar?) In either case, whether looking for the index in the string, or in the array, you can loop looking for `'W'`. In the case of the string it's just a single loop. In the case of the array you would loop `row = 0; row < nrows` and have an inner loop of `col = 0; col < ncols` comparing if `array[row][col] == 'W'` and breaking returning or outputting `row, col` when it is found.

Comment: If you are given `'W'` is at index `5` in the string and there are 4-columns in the 2D array, then the direct 2D coordinates can be computed as @v78 indicates (with integer division intentional in the `x` term)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what @v78 is saying I guess. How is `x` and `y` calculated?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right the stuff is computed like `@v78` commented however the topology (s)he used is different than yours (has swapped x,y)...

its exploiting modular arithmetic (done on integer arithmetic)...

`/` is division

 `%` is remainder after division

If you still do not know what `%` does it you can look at it like this:

```
a%b = a - (a/b)*b
```

so `a/b` get truncated to integer so if you multiply it again by `b` it will be less than `a` unless `b` divides `a` exactly. so the substraction of both will give you remainder. You can rewrite it to this:

```
(a/b)*b + a%b = a
```

**Back to your question** so if `cols` is number of columns  `col,row` are 2D array position and `i` is linear position and `n` is size then:

```cpp
i = row*cols + col     // get string index from array position

row = i/cols           // get array position from string index
col = i%cols

rows = (n+cols-1)/cols // number of rows from string size
```

Answer (score 0):

This program solves your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


main() {
    string str= "Hello World";
    //declare an array 2d 
    char array[3][4];
    int s=0;
    //simple nested for loop
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            //extracting character from string and assigning in array
            //condition because string maybe shorter then 2d array cells
            if(s<str.length()){
                array[i][j]= str.at(s);
            }
            s++;
            cout<<array[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    //here our first problem is solved

    //second problem starts i-e finding the position of character 
    char inp;
    //creating in case user enters some character that is not in array
    bool found= false;
    cout<<"Enter character to get position of character ";
    cin>>inp;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            if(array[i][j]==inp){
                cout<<"Found at "<<i<<", "<<j<<endl;
                found= true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(found==false){
        cout<<"This character is not present in this array";
    }
}
```

I hope everything will be clear to you from commented parts.

Comment: Yes it should be a 3x4 2D array. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not actually concerned if the character is in the array or not. I'm able to do that. I'm trying to figure what position it is in based on the arrays in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int position=0;//let us create this variable
    cout<<"Enter character to get position of character ";
    cin>>inp;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            if(array[i][j]==inp){
                cout<<"Found at "<<position<<endl;
                found= true;
            }
            position++;
        }
    }
    if(found==false){
        cout<<"This character is not present in this array";
    }
```

I mis-interperated by the term Position last time. Now this will help you.
Update second part of program like this.